# Thread safe calls to windows form are freezing the application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

I have an Exception Handling project in my application that can be called from anywhere to show the user there is a problem with with system.   Everything works great when the call is made from somewhere in the UI as expected.  When I make calls from no UI parts of the application everything freezes.  I have the code wrapped in the thread safe calls and when stepping through they don't require the Invoke call.   Any help is greatly appreciated. Code below:

Inside the form

```
    void err_DispEvent(string text)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new Error.DisplayDelegate(err_DispEvent), new object [] {text});
        }
        else
        {
            this.Show();
        }        
    }
```

Call from the class

```
public void FaultError(string errorMsg)
    {
        FaultForm fform = new FaultForm(errorMsg, "Internal Fault");
        if (this.dispEvent != null)
        {
            dispEvent(errorMsg);
        }
    }

    public event DisplayDelegate DispEvent
    {
        add { dispEvent += value; }
        remove { dispEvent -= value; }
    }

    private event DisplayDelegate dispEvent;

    public delegate void DisplayDelegate(string text);
```

Sample of how the class is used in the application

```
ECDUExceptions.Error newError = ECDUExceptions.Error.getInstance();
newError.FaultError("Heater is not responding to function calls, it has been turned off");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some information when re-invoking methods:

1. Use `BeginInvoke(...)` instead of `Invoke(...)` as this will not wait for the call to finish, and so won't freeze the calling thread.
2. Use an `Action` when re-invoking. So in your case, you could change your invocation to:

   ```
   BeginInvoke(new Action<string>(err_DispEvent), text);
   ```

Comment: if the signatures match, isn't `BeginInvoke(err_DispEvent, text);` sufficient?

Comment: @codesparkle I believe so, I wrote the full lot in to be more explicit.

Comment: would you mind if I propose an edit to your question (showing both alternatives)?

Comment: I have switched the code to the full signature version, but I am still seeing the problem.   InvokeRequired is always false (which doesnt' make sense to me) so I am never calling the BeginInvoke command

Comment: `InvokeRequired` being `false` indicates you are running on the UI thread when you hit that point.

Comment: I'm am at a loss then as to what would be causing the freeze.  The screen is not shown when in the frozen state, it stays at the last screen

Comment: When the application freezes, press the pause button in Visual Studio and study what line the code is currently executing and what threads are running. That may help you to identify the cause of the freeze.

Comment: Figured it out.. another thread was blocking on a call.. proper error checking was not placed around that code.  Thank you for the assistance!

Answer (score 1):

Use BeginInvoke(...) instead of Invoke(...). THis will put your message request in the end of the queue

Answer (score 0):

Create a queue of some sort for the messages that should be displayed.

Fill the queue from whatever thread you required.

From the GUI responsible for showing the messages, use timer to dequeue and show them.

Simplistic but will work effortlessly.  And you won't need to Invoke() anything since Forms.Timer runs on UI message loop.

Comment: Such a queue already exists: the message loop.
Use BeginInvoke() to add an action at the end of the queue.